# Why am I getting SQL syntax error in Moodle 3.3?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, moodle

I installed a plugin on Moodle 3.3 and now I'm getting SQL syntax error and `Error reading from database`. I did some PHP debugging giving the following description:

```
Debug info: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR target = LIMIT 0, 1' at line 1
SELECT 'x' FROM mdl_dasis_relations WHERE source = OR target = LIMIT 0, 1 [array ( )]
Error code: dmlreadexception
Stack trace:
line 486 of /lib/dml/moodle_database.php: dml_read_exception thrown
line 1184 of /lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php: call to moodle_database->query_end()
line 1889 of /lib/dml/moodle_database.php: call to mysqli_native_moodle_database->get_recordset_sql()
line 1874 of /lib/dml/moodle_database.php: call to moodle_database->record_exists_sql()
line 76 of /blocks/semantic_web/block_semantic_web.php: call to moodle_database->record_exists_select()
line 709 of /blocks/moodleblock.class.php: call to block_semantic_web->get_content()
line 230 of /blocks/moodleblock.class.php: call to block_list->formatted_contents()
line 1205 of /lib/blocklib.php: call to block_base->get_content_for_output()
line 1257 of /lib/blocklib.php: call to block_manager->create_block_contents()
line 579 of /lib/outputrenderers.php: call to block_manager->ensure_content_created()
line 39 of /theme/bootstrapbase/renderers/core_renderer.php: call to core_renderer->standard_head_html()
line 44 of /theme/clean/layout/columns3.php: call to theme_bootstrapbase_core_renderer->standard_head_html()
line 1162 of /lib/outputrenderers.php: call to include()
line 1092 of /lib/outputrenderers.php: call to core_renderer->render_page_layout()
line 68 of /course/index.php: call to core_renderer->header()
```

I also did some investigations and I think this is the part of the `block_semantic_web.php` file throwing the error:

```
    function setLastActivity() {
    global $USER, $PAGE, $DB;
    if($PAGE->cm) {
        if($DB->record_exists_select("dasis_relations", "source = ".$PAGE->cm->id." OR target = ".$PAGE->cm->id)) {
            $lastActivity = new object();
            $lastActivity->userid = $USER->id;
            $lastActivity->courseid = $PAGE->cm->course;
            $lastActivity->course_module = $PAGE->cm->id;

            if($rec = $DB->get_record("dasis_last_activity", array("userid" => $lastActivity->userid, "courseid" => $lastActivity->courseid))) {
                $lastActivity->id = $rec->id;
                $lastActivity->last_access = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
                $DB->update_record("dasis_last_activity", $lastActivity);
            }else{
                $DB->insert_record("dasis_last_activity", $lastActivity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what the syntax error is exactly.

PHP: `7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1`

MySQL: `Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.26`

Comment: Looks like `$PAGE->cm->id` is undefined, or not suppose to be addressed that way. What does `var_dump($PAGE->cm->id, $PAGE->cm, $PAGE)` give you?

Comment: @user3783243 It gives this notice: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/moodle/blocks/semantic_web/block_semantic_web.php on line 283`  and then a large array.

Comment: @user3783243 Individually, `$PAGE->cm->id` gives the notice, followed by `NULL`. `$PAGE->cm` gives just `NULL` and `$PAGE` gives the array.

Comment: Why are you building this query with string concatenation? `"source = ".$PAGE->cm->id." OR target = ".$PAGE->cm->id`  In addition to bring error-prone, it's extremely unsafe from a security perspective as a general rule. `record_exists_select()` supports parameters.  https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#record_exists_select

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot It's part of the plugin files that I installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$PAGE->cm->id` may not be defined, for example, it is not defined in pages outside a activity/course module context (course view, home page, profile, etc.). I recommend you to check if it is not empty before calling `setLastActivity` or `$DB->record_exists_select`. Like so:

```
global $PAGE;
if (!empty($PAGE->cm->id)) {
    // ...
}
```

Then (as someone noticed before), you may call it by passing the parameters separately to avoid any sort of SQL injection vulnerability:

```
$select = 'source = :source OR target = :target';
$params = ['source' => $PAGE->cm->id, 'target' => $PAGE->cm->id];
$DB->record_exists_select('dasis_relations', $select, $params);
```